# Monthly or per month

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Which word is correct in the following sentence

> They pay him handsome salary and he is earning fifteen thousand rupees **monthly/per month**.

I think both are correct

Comment: To my knowledge, you are correct on here. Although bothe are correct, I'd prefer "per month" to go with the flow of the sentence.

Comment: I agree, but I think it should be: 'They pay him **a** handsome salary [...]'.